# "Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined" error - Plaid link token

Tags: swift, google-cloud-functions, plaid

I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined" when trying to create a plaid token....I have spent like 3 days trying to make it work.

**does anybody knows how to fix it?**

[image]
Cloud function to get Plaid token

```
//PLAID - create link Token plaid Nat
const plaid = require("plaid");

exports.createPlaidLinkToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const customerId = context.auth.uid;

  const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({
    clientID: functions.config().plaid.client_id,
    secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
    env: plaid.environments.development,
    options: {
      version: "2019-05-29",
    },
  });

  return plaidClient.createLinkToken({
      user: {
        client_user_id: customerId,
      },
      client_name: "Reny",
      products: ["auth"],
      country_codes: ["US"],
      language: "en",
    })
    .then((apiResponse) => {
      const linkToken = apiResponse.link_token;
      return linkToken;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "internal",
        " Unable to create plaid link token: " + err
      );
    });
});
```

swift function

```
    class func createLinkToken(completion: @escaping (String?) -> ()){
        //this is the firebase function
        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createPlaidLinkToken").call { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return completion(nil)
            }
            guard let linkToken = result?.data as? String else {
                return completion(nil)
            }
            completion(linkToken)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only `.uid` in your code is in this line:

```
const customerId = context.auth.uid;
```

So it seems like `context.auth` is `undefined`. In the Cloud Functions code you can handle this with:

```
exports.createPlaidLinkToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Checking that the user is authenticated.
  if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
      'while authenticated.');
  }

  const customerId = context.auth.uid;
  ...
```

The new code here comes from the Firebase documentation on [handling errors in callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors).

You'll also want to [check if the user is signed in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) in your Swift code.

Comment: how embarrassing, your response made me realize I've been testing all this time without the user being authenticated haha.
I authenticated and I was able to pass that error, now I'm getting "Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'development' of undefined" but I guess that's related to the env and I can debug that tomorrow. thanks!